# Хочется поставить запятую и кавычки

Tags: запятые, кавычки

Но в других государствах этого региона беспорядков такого масштаба не наблюдалось, несмотря на то(,) что численность молодежи в них даже выше.

С одной стороны зрителям интересно, каким образом будет развиваться сама история, потому что в ней присутствует некая интрига(,) и она достаточно динамична,...

Обычно, перед тем как предстать перед аудиторией, ему задают вопрос, догадывается ли он о том, кто мог его позвать(,) и с кем у него есть нерешенное дело.

Нужны ли зпт в скобках?

Они употребляют к вместо г (противопоставление город-деревня).

Надо ли взять к и г в кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Но в других государствах этого региона беспорядков такого масштаба не наблюдалось, несмотря на то, что численность молодежи в них даже выше*.-Есть указательное слово - запятую ставим.

*С одной стороны зрителям интересно, каким образом будет развиваться сама история, потому что в ней присутствует некая интрига и она достаточно динамична,..*.- Однородные придаточные - нет запятой.

*Обычно, перед тем как предстать перед аудиторией, ему задают вопрос, догадывается ли он о том, кто мог его позвать и с кем у него есть нерешенное дело.*-Однородные придаточные - нет запятой.

*Они употребляют к вместо г (противопоставление город-деревня).*

```
    Надо ли взять к и г в кавычки?
```

В кавычки обычно не берут, а вот чем-то выделить можно - курсивом,жирным шрифтом, большой буквой. Но если очень  хочется, возьмите в кавычки - за ошибку не сочтут.